# Python filepaths have double backslashes

Tags: python-3.x, python-os

Ultimately, I want to loop through every pdf in specified directory ('C:\Users\dude\pdfs_for_parsing') and print the metadata for each pdf. The issue is that when I try to loop through the "directory" I'm receiving the error "**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:**". I understand this error is occurring because I now have double slashes in my filepaths for some reason.

### Example Code

```
import PyPDF2
import os

path_of_the_directory = r'C:\Users\dude\pdfs_for_parsing'

directory = []
ext = ('.pdf')

def isolate_pdfs():
    for files in os.listdir(path_of_the_directory):
        if files.endswith(ext):
            x = os.path.abspath(files)
            directory.append(x)

    for pdf in directory:
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf)
        information = reader.metadata
        print(information)
        
isolate_pdfs()
```

If I print the file paths one at a time, I see that the files have single '/' like I'm expecting:

```
for pdf in directory:
    print(pdf)
```

The '//' seems to get added when I try to open each of the PDFs 'PDFFile = open(pdf,'rb')'

Comment: I've adjusted how you should use PyPDF2

Answer (score 2):

Your issue has nothing to do with //, it's here:

```
os.path.abspath(files)
```

Say you have `C:\Users....\x.pdf`, you list that directory, so the `files` will contain `x.pdf`. You then take the absolute path of `x.pdf`, which the abspath supposes to be in the current directory. You should replace it with:

```
x = os.path.join(path_of_the_directory, files)
```

Other notes:

- `PDFFile` and `PDF` shouldn't be in uppercase. Prefer `pdf_file` and `pdf_reader`. The latter also avoids the confusion with the `for pdf in...`
- Try to use a debugger rather than print statements. This is how I found your bug. It can be in your IDE or in command line with `python -i` You can step through your code, test a few variations, fiddle with the variables...
- Why is `ext = ('.pdf')` with braces ? It doesn't do anything but leads to think that it might be a tuple (but isn't).
- As an exercise the first for can be written as: `directory = [os.path.join(path_of_the_directory, x) for x in os.listdir(path_of_the_directory) if x.endswith(ext)]`